# How to use replace function in mysql?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to replace a particular id using replace function if column assign having string like 4,5,6,7. Then how can I run this query it show me 0 row affected message. So, How can I do this ?Please help me. Here's my query.

```
$data = array('assign' => REPLACE(assign,'$id',''),);
$where = "sub_category_name = '".$sub_category_name."'";
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->update('assign_category', $data);
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Thank You

Comment: try with this : '$id' to $id OR '".$id."'

Comment: not working @ShaunakShukla

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` let us know what is the rendered query. I can see that `$data = array('assign' => REPLACE(assign,'$id',''),);` has REPLACE() which is not a part of codeigniter, that's why you're getting undefined error.

Comment: Thank you Shaunak Shukla I have sorted out my problem. Thank You every one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code replace all ID( what you assigned before) to zero length string in assign the column of the assign_category table.

```
$data = array('assign' => 'REPLACE(assign,' . $id . ',\' \')');
$where = "sub_category_name = '".$sub_category_name."'";
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->update('assign_category', $data);
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: If I use your query it update REPLACE(assign,' . 4 . ',\'\') as value of assign column. I want to replace 4 with space @zhilevan

Comment: @omkara I update my question, it converts 4  with ' ' (space) . try it and inform me about the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->set('assign', 'REPLACE(assign, "'.$id.'", "")',false);
$this->db->where('sub_category_name',$sub_category_name);
$query = $this->db->update('assign_category');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: please take a look my question I have doing some changes @Vijay Sharma

Comment: when I run this query it show me  Call to undefined function REPLACE()

Comment: @omkara sorry bro first ill test then ill update answer ok

Answer (score 0):

try Like this :

```
$data = array('assign' => '', );
$where = "assign like replace('assign'," . $id. ",'')";//Made changes here to append '$id' variable.
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->update('assign_category',$data);
```

Comment: please check my question again I have doing some changes @Ketan Solanki

Comment: when I run this query it show me  Call to undefined function REPLACE()